# Function keys change wrong backlight file on my Acer Aspire One

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, acer, backlight

Whenever I press the function keys to change my laptop's screen brightness, it modifies the value stored in the file `/sys/class/backlight/acer-wmi/brightness`, but my screen stays the same. With a bit of experimentation, I discovered that manually modifying the value stored in `/sys/class/backlight/psb-bl/brightness` will instantly change my screen's brightness.

How can I either make the function keys change `acer-wmi`'s file, or make my backlight take its brightness from `psb-bl`'s file?

Some details that may be of use:

- I am running Lubuntu 15.10.
- My laptop is an Acer Aspire One.
- My `/etc/default/grub` has

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
  ```

  If I remove `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor`, the same problem remains (with one minor difference: the `acer-wmi` link in `/sys/class/backlight` is changed to a different name -- I think it was `acpi_video0`).
- Running `xbacklight` in terminal results in `No outputs have backlight property`.
- When attempting to change brightness with the function keys, a bar appears in the corner of my screen that shows the current value of `acer-wmi`'s file.
- `acer-wmi` ranges from 0 to 9, and `psb-bl` ranges from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

In lubuntu you can use [openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page) window manager to create bindings between a key and a action, e.g. to execute a shell script which edits your `/sys/class/backlight/psb-bl/brightness`. Create a new binding in the rc.xml file, which contains the mappings for your key bindings::

```
<keybind key="key code">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>~/brightnessDown.sh</execute>
      </action>
 </keybind>
```

You can verify the key code with a tool like `showkeys` or `xev`. The content of the file `brightnessDown.sh` should look like:

```
backlight=`cat /sys/class/backlight/psb-bl/brightness`;
if [ $backlight -gt 1 ]; then
       backlight=$((backlight - 1));
       echo $backlight > /sys/class/backlight/psb-bl/brightness;
fi
```